# PHP echo not displaying inside of HTML <h3> tags

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

On my page, I have a bunch of information fetched from my SQL database via PHP PDO.

```
$query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT `balance`,`followers`,`following` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
$query->bindValue(1,$logged);
$query->execute();
$followerslist=$query->fetch();
$userbalance=$followerslist['balance'];
?>

<div class="span4">
    <h3>
        <?=$userbalance;?>
    </h3>
</div>
```

The above displays nothing.  Just blank.  However, when I remove the `<h3>` tags, it works!  If I `echo $userbalance;` outside of the `<h3>` block, it works as well.  If I change `$userbalance` to equal some random text instead of data set from a SQL table, it works inside the `<h3>` block.  For some reason it refuses to display this information coming from my SQL table.

Yet, whenever I `echo` the "followers" and "following" inside the same `<h3>` blocks, it works.  To be clear, "balance" is a numerical value.

Comment: Do you maybe have some CSS that says `h3 {display: none;}` or anything like that? What output do you see when you *view source* in your browser?

Comment: Try `<h3><?=(string)$userbalance?></h3>`.  Are 'followers' and 'following' strings?

Comment: what does `var_dump($userbalance);` say ?

Comment: @aelieo Tried it, no dice.  And yes, those two are strings.

Comment: @Jigar The result is:  string(5) "92485"

Comment: The weird part about this, is its happening across almost every webpage on my site.

Comment: @Austin Look at the page source. Do you see those numbers there? If yes then the problem is with CSS/HTML code of the page.

Comment: Looked through the CSS, nothing of that nature in there.

Comment: What happens if you use '<?php echo ' instead of shorthand '<?='? Also what is the value of '$userbalance'? You are saying, it's numerical value however it seems, somehow it is messing up with the tags.

Comment: When I view source, the correct text shows up.  I just cannot view it on the webapge.  @GolezTrol

Comment: Do you use Firebug or something by which you can check corresponding CSS for h3 like @GolezTrol said. Or try other tag like `h1` or `h2` (just for testing purpose)

Comment: @Austin maybe something like `h3 {color:white}` would prevent the text from appearing? if you try to select it, can you copy paste it?

Comment: Have you **confirmed** (by testing elsewhere) that your server is configured to interpret php within '<?= ... ?>` sequences? Many servers don't. That's the point of trying `<?php` instead.

Comment: @Austin, Have you checked size, opacity etc CSS properties for class 'span4'? or 'h3'? Once, try with removing class 'span4', if it works that means it's a CSS issue.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I can copy paste the text, but cannot find anything in the CSS dictating color white

Comment: @WisdmLabs Does not work without Span4

Comment: well... this is funny. From that my last guess would be to open firebug and verify with the css analyzer which css rules apply on this specific `h3`

Comment: @WisdmLabs The value is "92475" - an integer

Comment: If you do see the text (that is, the actual HTML output, not the PHP source) when you view source, then the problem is most likely not in the PHP code, but in the styling. If you see the PHP code in your browser, then either you are missing a PHP opening tag, or PHP is not running on your server at all, in which case the PHP source is sent as static content.

Comment: Do you have a url to your webpage that we can try from here? Maybe a picture says more than 1000 comments.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for your help, I'm going to spend the better part of my afternoon looking through the CSS.  It's a really weird anomaly thats for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem!

Inside "bootstrap.css" there was a line called "  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;  ".  Once I disabled this, everything worked again.  Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: well, we had the pleasure of awakening some zealous troll in the meantime, but glad you could find this out. Don't forget to accept your answer so that this question can disappear from view quietly

Answer (score 0):

Leandro Oliva is right regarding opening tags. The snippet of code you provided missing `<?php` opening tags. For further debugging I suggest turning error_reporting on. You might be aware of this but this is the php built in function `error_reporting(E_ALL)` more details can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: Even doing <?php echo $userbalance; ?> does not work.  Will try error reporting

Answer (score 0):

I was referring to the query string.
Here's your code

```
$query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT `balance`,`followers`,`following` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
$query->bindValue(1,$logged);
$query->execute();
$followerslist=$query->fetch();
$userbalance=$followerslist['balance'];
?>
```

Here's what code should look like with proper opening tags.

```
<?php 
//shorthand  opening tag should work as well 
//if this is the second line of php script 
//place error reporting function before any script begins but after php opening tag
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT `balance`,`followers`,`following` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
$query->bindValue(1,$logged);
$query->execute();
$followerslist=$query->fetch();
$userbalance=$followerslist['balance'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work or return any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe username should equal to a string. You have `"username"=?` it should be `"username"="bob"`.

Comment: Be sure to use single quotes instead of  double quotes. This website omitted single quotes initially so I had to switch to double quotes to communicate my point.